# Vector of std::shared_ptr not freeing memory

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, vector, shared-ptr

First time posting on here, and I'm not a CS guy, so please bear with me. I have a good sized, code, so I will post a bare-bones version of my problem below and then explain it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A{

public: 
  A(){};
  double dbl[20];
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr;

class B{
  public:
  const std::vector<A_ptr> createAVector(){
    std::vector<A_ptr> vec;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
      vec.push_back(A_ptr( new A() ));
    }
    return vec;
  }
};

int myfunc(){

  // Do Stuff...

  std::vector<A_ptr> globvec;

  B b;
  for(int i=0; i<1e6; i++){
    const std::vector<A_ptr> locvec = b.createAVector();

    for(int i=0; i<locvec.size(); i++) globvec.push_back(locvec[i]);

  }

  globvec.clear();
  globvec.shrink_to_fit();

  // Do more stuff...

  return 1;
}


int main(){

  myfunc();

  for(auto i=0; i<3; i++){
    myfunc();
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Edit: I modified the code so it actually compiles.

So, basically I have two classes. Class A stores the actual data. Class B, among other things, creats a vector of std::shared_ptrs to A and returns it. I then assemble these local vectors into a large global vector in a function called myfunc. To test that memory is freed when I want to shrink the size of globA, I call globA.clear() and globA.shrink_to_fit().

The problem is that calling clear() and shrink_to_fit() does not free the memory of all the A's created.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Any idea what might be going on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

John

Comment: Are you sure the problem occurs with the code you posted? Seems like you may have simplified out the issue. Also, it is helpful to post a self-contained, compilable example. The code you have here does not compile.

Comment: I don't see anything there that might indicate the memory is not being released.  What makes you think that there's a problem?

Comment: how did you establish that not all `A`s are deleted ?

Comment: If you're checking a Task Manager or similar for memory use, deallocations don't necessarily show up there. The C++ runtime often holds on to memory after release.

Comment: How about check globA.get==null?

Comment: After correcting some errors that made the posted code uncompilable, valgrind says that there are no leaks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help, your current code is non-compilable, besides other obvious errors. I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: If you're going to keep millions of shared_ptrs in a `vector`, it might be a good idea to create them with `make_shared<A>()` instead of `shared_ptr<A>(new A())` to avoid wasting memory.

Comment: Go to ideone.com and copy/paste your code there, then get it to compile.  Include a `main` and the like.  Keep it minimal.  This will help eliminate your syntax errors and make it easier to understand where your mistake is!  The problem is mistakes that are clear to you (just typos), and mistakes that cause your problem, look **the same** to us looking over your code -- they are both mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I'll try to make a compilable code and update it. molbdnilo: I am using the task manager to establish that the memory has not been released. Maybe that's the problem. If so, why is this not a valid approach? Is the memory actually not released until after the program terminates, or does it just appear that way to the task manager? If so, is there a way to make sure it is actually deleted during runtime? Maybe by statically linking everything?

Comment: User, Task Manager reports memory usage from the OS perspective, not from your program's perspective. Within your program, a request for a small amount of memory will typically result in your program requesting a much larger block of memory from the OS. The run-time library of your program then uses that large block to fulfill many subsequent allocations. When you free memory, regions of that large block become available, but as long as *any* allocation from that block is still active, the memory remains in your program and is not returned to the OS. Task Manager only sees the large block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ delete does not free all memory (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008180/c-delete-does-not-free-all-memory-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.  You can essentially 'prove' that you are not leaking `A` objects with this... (I also had to reduce the number of iterations from 1e6 to get any reasonable runtime).

There are more sophisticated tools for finding memory leaks.  I know for Linux we use Valgrind.  I don't know what the Windows equivalent is however.

```
class A{

public: 
  A() { std::cout << "Created A " << ++num_instances << std::endl;}
  ~A() { std::cout << "Destroyed A " << --num_instances << std::endl;}

  static int num_instances; // So not thread-safe

  double dbl[20];
};

int A::num_instances = 0;
```

Comment: Use InterlockedIncrement() and InterlockedDecrement() instead of ++ and -- and then it will be a bit safer for a multi-threaded environment.