# C++ pointer struct does not get deleted

Tags: c++, struct, nodes

I have build a custom data-struct, that is something like a doubly linked RBTree, and while the logic seems fine, I don't see any memory getting released when I delete a node.

This is my node declaration:

```
typedef struct rbtreere_node
{

public:
    NMessage *n_message;

    // Node Specific //
    enum color color_ID;    //<<--- Color for ID side of RBTreeRe
    enum color color_Price; //<<--- Color for Price side of RBTreeRe
    int id;                 //<<--- Unique Identifier.
    rbtreere_node *left_ID, *right_ID, *parent_ID, *left_Price, *right_Price, *parent_Price;

}*node;
```

When I call my remove function, I end with a `delete n` before my return.
I checked and if I try to access any of the `node n` data before returning, it is still there...

i.e. I'm calling this:

```
delete n;
std::cout << n->color_ID<<"\n\n";
```

and it does return a the node color

Should I build a custom destructor for it?

I also had the `node message` as a var, instead of a pointer, but that did not seem to change anything...

Edit: My issue is that I do not see any drop in memory usage after deleting any or even all nodes. Should I handle it differently?

Comment: After performing the `delete n;` operation, you can force the pointer to `n = NULL;`... No way to recover data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I checked and if I try to access any of the node n data before returning, it is still there...

```
delete n;
std::cout << n->color_ID<<"\n\n";
```

Dereferencing `n` after it has been deleted has undefined behaviour.

> Should I build a custom destructor for it?

No. Unless `n_message` owns the memory it points, in which case the implicit destructor would leak that memory.

> My issue is that I do not see any drop in memory usage after deleting any or even all nodes.

Most implementations of `malloc` (which is what is typically used for dynamic memory allocation by the implementation of `new`) never return freed memory to the operating system. Instead it reuses it for subsequent allocations. This is a non-issue.

> Should I handle it differently?

Besides getting rid of the "check" that has UB, no. Everything appears to be as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` only deallocates memory and calls the object's destructor. It doesn't wipe the memory or do anything like that. And unless you have some need to (security, for instance) it's just a waste of time and code. After `delete` you can (and obviously are) still point to the memory and dereference it. It's very dangerous to do as it is undefined behavior.

Comment: what about calling the destructor? The `delete` would invoke the dtor if there is any, before deallocating memory.

Comment: My issue is that I do not see any drop in memory usage after deleting any or even all nodes. Should I handle it differently?

Comment: @LucaCappa Of course it does, but since the OP is deleting the memory there doesn't appear to be any reason to erase the contents of the `color_ID` field the OP is referencing. So he/she can still see the value only because the OS has re-purposed the memory yet.

Comment: i just wanted to note that you written "delete *only* deallocates memory", while instead it also calls dtor before.

Comment: @LucaCappa Ah. Point taken.

Comment: @Ant The OS is likely managing memory in pages. If you aren't freeing enough memory to free an entire page you probably won't see any decrease. But you shouldn't concern yourself with that. Let the OS take care of the memory. Just make sure you `delete` correctly (insert the obligatory comment about using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` here).

Comment: @MichaelAlbers In my test, I add 10,000 nodes. Then delete all of them and then re-add 10,000 new ones. What I'm seeing is after deleting them, the memory usage remains the same and when adding the new nodes, it keeps increasing (albeit at about half the original size). Shouldn't it stay about the same levels?

Comment: @Ant Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008180/c-delete-does-not-free-all-memory-windows. It gives a pretty good answer. If you're running on Linux it will be doing the same sort of thing.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Maybe I'm leaking something else then... I did 5 loops with a million entries and every subsequent loop the memory usage increased by 50%.

Comment: @Ant Quite possible. Time to fire up valgrind.