# STL not release memory from System level

Tags: c++, memory, stl

As I know STL has automatic memory management. But when I use something like `top` or `ps -aux` to show the memory usage of a process, it shows even the STL object are out of scope, these memory is still possessed by process.

Here is an example:

```
void run()
{
    map<int, int> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    { 
        a[i] =  i;
    } // 64376K memory used by process
}

int main()
{
    run();
    sleep(5); // still 64376 memory used
    map<int, int> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    { 
        a[i] =  i;
    } // still 64376 memory used
    return 0;
}
```

The process possesses 64376KB memory in `run()` and memory doesn't release after function `run()`. But these memory seems to be used by the second `map`.

After I use `valgrind --tool=massif` to check what happened, I got a normal result.

[image]

So here comes my question

1. why process memory trends doesn't match with the code and `valgrind`
2. How does the different STL objects share the same allocated memory.

Comment: 1. Because that's how an operating system works. They do not immediately release memory back to the OS, because they can't. 2. They don't.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417318/why-does-the-free-function-not-return-memory-to-the-operating-system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely normal. That's how operating systems work. If they spent all their time reclaiming tiny portions of memory from tiny processes, they'd never do anything else.

You just have to trust that their complicated algorithms know what they're doing to get the best performance for your system.

There are layers on layers on layers of logic that allocate physical RAM all the way up to the process's virtual memory.

Going into extreme detail about how operating systems work would be both beyond the scope of this post, and pointless. However, you could enrol on a relevant teaching course if you really wanted to grok it all.

If we were to forget about caching and virtual memory and such, even a simple rule of thumb might be summarised as follows: **releasing memory from your program tells the OS it can have it back; that doesn't mean the OS must take it back.**

Comment: So it there an effective way to monitor the true memory usage of the process except valgrind, it's maybe too slow?

Comment: @LTzycLT Basically. I usually don't bother, except maybe once in a while to get a general feel for my memory consumption, but keep an eye on overall memory consumption during long-term tests for early detection of any serious memory leaks.